# Kotlin Javascript: Assigning to element property inside event handler gives "Expected a value of type dynamic"

Tags: html, kotlin, kotlin-js

I am using the Kotlin to Javascript transpilation.

I have this function to edit a div's contents when a textarea changes.

```
fun doStuff()
{
    val div = document.createElement("div") as HTMLDivElement
    val textarea = document.createElement("textarea") as HTMLTextAreaElement

    textarea.onchange = {
        div.innerHTML = "5"
    }
    div.innerHTML = textarea.value
}
```

The line for `div.innerHTML = "5"`has an error of "Expected a value of type dynamic", but `div.innerHTML = textarea.value` never has an error.

Why do I get the "Expected a value of type dynamic" inside the onchange handler, even though the same line of code outside the event handler would not give an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I was setting the event handler incorrectly. Instead of assigning to `.onchange =`, you can instead use:

```
textarea.addEventListener("keyup", {
    event : Event -> Unit 
    ... 
}
```

Something about my previous code created a closure that didn't accept the assignment code.

Comment: Thanks for leaving an answer after you figured it out. This helped me.

Answer (score 4):

To make a bit more clear, what the problem here is:
`.onchange` (or any other event method) expects an `{(Event)->dynamic}?` as argument.

so if you insert a lambda, your last line is used as the return value. Changing your code to the following would also work:

```kotlin
textarea.onchange = {
    div.innerHTML = "5"
    Unit
}
```